# User Profile Synchronization Service is not starting at all

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, user-profile, user-profile-service, profile-sync

I have a User Profile Service and User Profile Synchronization Service. This is what I did. I went into powershell and

typed: get-spserviceinstance
and I got all the services status. The next step was I typed: Stop-SpServiceInstance  and this stopped the service for my user profile synchronization. The last step I did was went into central administration and under manage services on services. Click on start for user profile synchronization service and it asked for the password and after which it is showing the status as starting and it is struct for long time and the same moment i start getting tons of errors and when i look into the services.msc and see Forefront Identity Manager and Synchronization is was not started even after i started that the services is not starting but the error got reduced.

Can anyone please help with this crazy problem.

Thanks
Mohammed

Comment: Check this one https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/44898d06-6b45-45e4-99c6-13c626a51907/user-profile-synchronization-service-stuck-on-starting?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Comment: Detailed explanation http://myspexp.com/2011/04/28/user-profile-synchronization-servicehangs-on-starting-i-fixed-it/

Answer (score 0):

Are you performing this action using a farm account? User profile sync will only start using a farm account.

Comment: I am doing this in my computer since I have Full Control. I do not see Manage Services on server in central administration at my farm computer? Is that right?

Comment: In Central Administration go to _System Settings > Manage Services on Server_ Make sure "User Profile Service' is started before attempting to Start "User Profile Synchronisation Service". This MUST be done while logged in using a FARM account.

Comment: But in my Farm Computer Under System Settings I only see this
Manage Servers in this Farm

Comment: Whereas in my own login I see Manage Services on Server and 
User Profile Service  status is Started

Comment: If you go to Central Administration under 'Security' select **Configure service accounts**. 
In the first dropdown select Farm and ensure the account it is using for Farm is the account that you are using.

Comment: Yes, it is the same if i check from my login. but if i do the same from my server account and my login i am getting access denied with my login.

Answer (score 0):

I come across this situation recently. User profile service can give lot of headache from different angles.

Stop the UPS services again using powershell and login to the server using the SP_FARM account. Now go to ** Manage Services on the server** and start the "User Profile Services". Now wait for 5 minutes and check the services will be running.

Comment: But this is what I have been doing with no luck. One difference what I see is " In my Farm account I do not see Manage Services on Server" but on my regular computer when I go to Central administration I see Manage Services on server does it a reason why it is not starting

Comment: Are you using same browser in both environment? In your Desktop PC, are you using the farm account or different service accounts?